# Passing ClientInfo/ClientIdentifier on syscontext/connection with Hibernate for audit purposes

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, websphere, audit

I have a web service which processes inserts/updated data to DB. When client calls this webservice, **UserId**(currently logged in user to portal) will be sent in Request. I need to pass this userId to Db connection or set it in **sys context** for **Audit purpose**. we have existing audit tables and triggers to inserts/updates to Audit table after insert/update on actual table. So to track these changes I need to pass this UserId somehow to **connection** so that it can be retrieved from DB from Sys Context or $session and inserts in Audit table. I am currently using Spring and Hibernate transactions to process data with DB.

I tried to Set client info on Connection but it's not working. I tried below:

```
Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
SessionImpl sImpl=(SessionImpl) session;
Connection connection=sImpl.connection();
connection.setClientInfo("ClientUser", "ABC");
```

And also I am trying to set client info by calling Stored procedure **DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO** before performing operation on DB every time from application code.but I am not sue if it's a correct way to handle it.

I am trying it with both OCI and thin JDBC drivers but not able find a way to set this user id.

Can someone let me know if there is any efficient way to pass user id on sys context or with Connection. I am currently using **hibernate4, Spring, Websphere Server, Oracle DB.**

I am using Spring @Transactional to handle hibernate Connections and transactions to perform operation on DB.Connections are from Connection pool and I am using **org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean** for **dataSource**.

is there any way to have interceptor or wrapper around connection to set it when we get the connection from connection pool.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in [spring data JDBC Extensions for the Oracle Database](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.connection.html)

Chapter

> 8.2 Configuration of a Custom DataSource Connection Preparer
>
> ...but you could implement a ConnectionPreparer that would use the current users login id. That way you can capture user login information even if your data source is configured with a shared user name.

This is a solution for oracle, which I think you are using. It should be also possible to adapt that to another database.