# Spring Custom DataSource Connection with JNDI on WebSphere server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, websphere, aop

I have a same requirement as specified in post to **pass user id as client identifier for audit purposes.**
[Passing ClientInfo/ClientIdentifier on syscontext/connection with Hibernate for audit purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961790/passing-clientinfo-clientidentifier-on-syscontext-connection-with-hibernate-for/36971224#36971224)

I have followed the same approach as mentioned in **8.2.Configuration of a Custom DataSource Connection Preparer** http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.connection.html

Below is the piece of code which I have :

```
@Aspect
public class ClientIdentifierConnectionPreparer {

@AfterReturning(pointcut= "execution(* javax.sql.DataSource.getConnection(..))",
        returning = "connection")
public Connection setClientIdentifier(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    CallableStatement cs=connection.prepareCall("{call DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER('XXXX')}");
    cs.execute();
    cs.close();
    return connection;
}
```

}

I have configured **aop autoaspect proxy** as shown below.

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean id="connectionPreparer" 
        class="xx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.ClientIdentifierConnectionPreparer" />
```

I am deploying my web service in **websphere server**. Everything is working fine If I configure data source using **apache dbcp BasicDataSource**:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

Code is working fine with the above configuration. Once connection is returned, I am able to set value to client identifier and able to retrieve it from syscontext with audit trigger.

But We have actual data source configuration as shown below:

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
       <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/myDS"></property>
```

I cannot change this configuration as it is used by multiple applications and I have to follow the same. With the above configuration While deploying I am getting null pointer exception while creating data source bean. Below is the exception that I am getting:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
... 121 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:511)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:242)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1818)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1776)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1861)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
```

has anyone followed this approach before. It would be helpful if some one can provide instructions on how to proceed further to to resolve this error. 
is there any other recommended way to follow this approach. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE::**

I have tried with using ProxyInterface type as specified in below answer. I am able to resolve null pointer exception but I am getting errors with cglib proxies.

```
    DEBUG - Creating instance of bean 'sessionFactory'
DEBUG - Eagerly caching bean 'sessionFactory' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0'
DEBUG - Creating implicit proxy for bean 'dataSource' with 0 common interceptors and 2 specific interceptors
DEBUG - Creating CGLIB proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134@df1d109a]
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.equals(java.lang.Object)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final int com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.hashCode()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.lang.String com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.toString()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.isPreFiltered()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.io.PrintWriter com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getLogWriter() throws java.sql.SQLException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.isProxyTargetClass()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.isFrozen()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.setLogWriter(java.io.PrintWriter) throws java.sql.SQLException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.lang.Object com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.unwrap(java.lang.Class) throws java.sql.SQLException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.removeAdvice(org.aopalliance.aop.Advice)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.removeAdvisor(org.springframework.aop.Advisor)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.setExposeProxy(boolean)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final int com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.indexOf(org.springframework.aop.Advisor)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.lang.Class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getTargetClass()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final org.springframework.aop.TargetSource com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getTargetSource()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final int com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getLoginTimeout() throws java.sql.SQLException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.addAdvisor(int,org.springframework.aop.Advisor) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.isExposeProxy()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.addAdvisor(org.springframework.aop.Advisor) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.isWrapperFor(java.lang.Class) throws java.sql.SQLException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.sql.Connection com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getConnection() throws java.sql.SQLException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.addAdvice(int,org.aopalliance.aop.Advice) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.setLoginTimeout(int) throws java.sql.SQLException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.lang.Class[] com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getProxiedInterfaces()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.removeAdvisor(int) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.sql.Connection com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getConnection(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.sql.SQLException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final int com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.indexOf(org.aopalliance.aop.Advice)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.setPreFiltered(boolean)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.replaceAdvisor(org.springframework.aop.Advisor,org.springframework.aop.Advisor) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
Unable to proxy method [public final org.springframework.aop.Advisor[] com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getAdvisors()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
Unable to proxy method [public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.isInterfaceProxied(java.lang.Class)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.addAdvice(org.aopalliance.aop.Advice) throws org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.util.logging.Logger com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.getParentLogger() throws java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final java.lang.String com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.toProxyConfigString()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
WARN  - Unable to proxy method [public final void com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.setTargetSource(org.springframework.aop.TargetSource)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
DEBUG - Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#ca01323a': [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0]
Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@184af104: 
defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,transitionController,dataSource,
sessionFactory,transactionManager,persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor,
org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor
org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0,
pointCut,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor]; 
root of factory hierarchy
Retrieved dependent beans for bean '(inner bean)#c0432d95': [(inner bean)#ca01323a]
 ERROR - Context initialization failed
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [sessionfactory.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Post-processing of the FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 129 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Post-processing of the FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:252)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 139 more
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:212)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:494)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:379)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:164)
    ... 144 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
    at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:202)
    ... 151 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per WebSphere documentation, data sources using the `org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean` should define a `proxyInterface` of `javax.sql.DataSource`.

For example:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/myDS"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Source: [Configuring access to a Spring application data source](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tspr_config_data_access.html)

Comment: Thank you.. I have tried adding proxyInterface and able to resolve null pointer exception but getting other error. I have updated question with error trace. Can you please check once..

Comment: I looked at the error trace and this looks like a separate issue.  I would recommend opening a different question, since your initial question has been answered.  Your new error looks like an issue with Spring incorrectly trying to cast/subclass a `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` which is invalid.