# Jar file for websphere WSJdbcDataSource

Tags: java, spring, jar, websphere

Can someone let me know where to find **jar** file or source attachment for **com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.**

Comment: The source code should be available from IBM.  Google can find it.  Unfortunately, the download site seems to be offline at the moment.  Try again on Monday.

Comment: I tried in google but couldn't find anywhere. Could you please share me the link to check it? Thanks!!

Comment: Google for "Websphere source code".  You should be able to download the source code for the Websphere community edition from there.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have checked it in ibm developerworks site and yes it seems to be offline now..Will check back again later and see If I can find source code there..

Comment: Sorry for asking again and again but I checked in site https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/ it is up now but I dont know where to find source code. Could you please let me know where exactly I can find it..

Comment: Try here - https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/  (Websphere Liberty ...)

Answer (score 1):

This class is a WebSphere internal class (not published API or SPI).  Source code should not be publicly available.

To be a bit more helpful to your scenario, why do you want to know the source code?  Applications running on WebSphere cannot use this class directly, so there should be no reason that you need to know the implementation details of the class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445725/spring-custom-datasource-connection-with-jndi-on-websphere-server I have a use case like this and I am getting null pointer exception so I am trying to figure out why by debugging or by checking source code, so to that I need jar or source attachment for it..

Comment: Why it should not be available pubicly when application is directly accessing it to get db connection..

Comment: In common with most software that is not open source the source is not made available. If you post a question including information on your source, data source configuration, WebSphere version and the NullPointerException I'm sure one of the many WAS experts here will be able to help.

Comment: @Robert I recently posted an answer to the question you linked previously in comments.  Specifying a `proxyInterface` of `javax.sql.DataSource` should fix your problem, assuming you are experiencing the exact same problem as the user who posted that question.

Comment: @aguibert Thank you.. I will check it out  and let you know If I can resolve my issue with the same..