# Passing ClientInfo on connection with Hibernate and JBoss to DB2

Tags: hibernate, jboss, database-connection

For auditing purposes, we need to set the application name on the connection to our DB2 Z/OS Database. We use a JBoss EAP 6.3 application server, with about 20 war files deployed on it. For persistence we use JPA with Hibernate persistence provider.

For each war file we need to set a different application name on the connection clientInfo. That could be done easily with the following code snippet before each database action:

```
    Session hibernateSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    hibernateSession.doWork(new Work() {
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            connection.setClientInfo("ApplicationName", "TestClientInfo-war");
        }
    });
```

However, inserting a call in so many places seems to be less than optimal.

Spring has the "Custom DataSource Connection Preparer" - see [Passing ClientInfo/ClientIdentifier on syscontext/connection with Hibernate for audit purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961790/passing-clientinfo-clientidentifier-on-syscontext-connection-with-hibernate-for), for example.

What could be used when working with JBoss? I think we need to hook to that point in a datasource's lifecycyle, where the datasource is fetched from the pool and prepared for work with the application.

Has anyone tried this before? Many thanks for your help!